# C++ invert matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

The following dynamic array contains a non-symmetric n*n matrix (with n <=100):

```
int **matrix;
matrix = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[n];
```

Is there an extremely easy way to invert it? Ideally I'd only use something from the STL or download a single header file.

Comment: what do you mean by invert? try to give some sample input and output for it

Comment: I mean find the inverse of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Comment: @Adrian Since he calls this thing an nxn-matrix it seems rather obvious what he means by inversion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Eigen.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

You can map your array to an Eigen matrix and then perform efficient matrix inversion.

You must only include it.

I add that usually if you have to perform your inversion for linear system solving, it's better to use a matrix decomposition based on the properties of the matrix that you can exploit.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialLinearAlgebra.html

Answer (score 3):

Not **extremely** easy but it works: [Numerical Recipes in c](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) page 48, using LU decomposition.

Comment: Looks to be an interesting book! Just ordered one, should be a handy reference tool.

Comment: @john the C part of the book is actually free (but admittedly not very user friendly when browsing)